# Saving on Azure billing cost with App Services?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, containers, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have a .NET Core application currently running as an Azure App Service, and I need it to do a lot of 'work' only about a few times a day. In order to save on the hourly billing, this is the solution I developed:

1. *Using a runbook (Azure Automation)*: scale the App Service Plan to the 'Free' tier at 7:00 PM
2. *Using a runbook (Azure Automation)*: scale the App Service Plan back up to the premium tier at 8:00 AM
3. Hard-code my .NET Core application to ensure it only does the heavy 'work' between 8:00 AM and 7:00 PM

This is *fine* as it saves me a significant portion of cost, as I'm only paying for the hours in which the App Service Plan is scaled up to the premium tier. However it is definitely not ideal.

My question is - what design pattern should I implement in order to accomplish what I'm trying to do? I need a lot of compute resources but only for a few hours out of the day. I know AWS has 'spot' instances that you can configure - is there a similar mechanism in Azure?

Ideally I could implement a solution that involves me only paying for those heavy compute resources when I actually need it (e.g.: a few times a day, while the sun is up)

Thank you for any insight and help!

---

**EDIT** in regards to the type of computation, my summary is essentially *a few ML.NET trainers running in parallel with some moderate Elasticsearch document writing*

Comment: It depends on the nature of your application.  Is it something that could be converted into an Azure Function and run on a consumption plan?  Then you are only paying for it when you actually use it (down to the second) and it will auto-scale if your app can take advantage of horizontal scaling.  Again, it depends on what kind of work you are doing.

Comment: Thank you - I edited my answer to summarize the type of computation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty tough to answer this with the whole description of your workload being a "lot" of "heavy compute".

If you can put your "compute" into [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/), going serverless with a consumption plan will probably be the nicest solution. However, individual function executions have a given timeout, so you need to see if your app fits the bill.

As an alternative, you can put your application into an [Azure Container Instance](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/container-instances/), and spin that up on demand.

If you have REALLY high workload, you can use [Azure Batch](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/batch/). If your current workload can be done on an AppService plan, this may be "overkill".

The equivalent to AWS spot instances is called [Azure Spot Virtual Machines](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/spot/). You can also use them with Azure Batch.

Comment: Regarding 'a lot of work' - its a few ML.NET trainers running in parallel with some moderate Elasticsearch document writing. Would that still fit in Azure Funtions?

Comment: Yeah, I would give it a try. See this as a full tutorial for Azure Functions with ML.NET: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/serve-model-serverless-azure-functions-ml-net

Comment: Thank you! I like the notion of ACI as I can schedule it with Azure Logic Apps apparently. I'm going to give both a shot

Comment: Marking this one as the answer but both this answer and @thiago-custodio 's were very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can switch to Serverless. Host front end on Storage Accounts and back end move to Azure Functions (Consumption Plan).

PS: If it's a long running processing, it may not be the best solution unless you use Durable Functions.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the suggestion to use Azure Functions - re: the other person's answer, the computation is basically a few ML.NET trainers running in parallel with some moderate Elasticsearch document writing. Do you think it could still fit into the Azure Functions paradigm?

Comment: Some customers are using Azure Functions. (take a look at cases https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/case-studies). If you need GPU, then it's not the right service.

Comment: Hey are you saying there are enterprise customers that are using Azure Functions to train the ML.NET models? Or just that they're using Azure Functions

Comment: Both. If you search on the link I've shared you'll find enterprises using Azure Functions to train their models